# how to prove that $ A^{(B \cup C)} \approx A^B\times A^C $

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

define: $ A \approx B $  $ \iff $ exists bijection $ f:A \to B $

let $B,C $ be such $ B\cap C=\emptyset $

I want to prove that $ A^{(B \cup C)} \approx A^B\times A^C $

$ A^{(B \cup C)} $ = the set of all the functions from $ B\cup C $ to $ A $

I dont have any idea of how to define the bijection so it would satisfy the terms.

Also, Im trying to learn this subject independently, so any tips about how to approach such questions will be helpful.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: Find two injections instead of one bijection. (See [Schröder–Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schröder–Bernstein_theorem))

Comment: HINT: If $f\in A^{B\cup C}$, you can decompose $f$ into its restrictions $f\upharpoonright B$ and $f\upharpoonright C$ to $B$ and $C$, respectively, and use them to define an element of $A^B\times A^C$. And the process is reversible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $x\in A^{(B\cup C)}$, define $f:A^{(B\cup C)}\rightarrow A^B\times A^C$ as $$fx=(x_1,x_2),\text{ where }x_1(b):=x(b),x_2(c):=x(c),\quad\forall b\in B,\forall c\in C.$$ Then $f$ is injection :

If $x\neq y$, then there exists $a\in B\cup C$ s.t. $x(a)\neq y(a)$, hence (let $a\in B$ without loosing generality) $(fx)(a,c)=(x(a),x(c))\neq (y(a),y(c))=(fy)(a,c)$, i.e. $fx\neq fy$.

On the other hand, for any $(x,y)\in A^B\times A^C$, let $g:A^B\times A^C\rightarrow A^{(B\cup C)}$ as $$g(x,y)(a)=\bigg\{\begin{array}&x(a)\quad\text{if }a\in B\\y(a)\quad\text{if }a\in C. \end{array}$$ Then again $g$ is injection :

If $(x,y)\neq (x',y')$, then either $x\neq x'$ or $y\neq y'$, so let $x\neq x'$ without loosing generality, then there exists $a\in B$ s.t. $x(a)\neq x'(a)$ so $g(x,y)(a)=x(a)\neq x'(a)=g(x',y')(a)$.

Therefore by Schröder-Bernstein theorem two sets have bijection.

Comment: Getting ö depends on your operating system; I’m running Ubuntu, so I can get it with the Compose key. I’ve done it for you here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks! I usually use $\"$ in my LaTex code, but it seems like not working in MathJax.

Comment: Your first map is from $A^{B\cup C}$ to $A^{B\times C}$, not to $A^B\times A^C$. You don’t need Schröder-Bernstein: your second map is a bijection, its inverse being the map $f\mapsto \langle f\upharpoonright B,f\upharpoonright C\rangle$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You are right on both points, but I have excuses : 1. Proper notation is rather confusing, and I thought the notation that I used will not missleading the points. Now I changed to the proper notation. 2.Actually the first map and second map are just inverse each other. Maybe I was lazy to state that, so just used the theorem.

Comment: Your first and second maps are **now** inverses, your first being the one that I just suggested; your original first map, however, had the wrong codomain altogether. In any case the proof that they are inverses of each other is at least as easy as the proof that both are injective, and it’s entirely possible that the S-B theorem is not a tool available to the OP: this is an elementary exercise that can be given long before the S-B theorem is encountered. Whether that’s the case for the OP or not, it very likely will be the case for some future readers.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Well, I agree with you. But I don't know StackExchange's philosophy in this case. Should I ellaborate my answer for the future readers? or let it like this so some other person can uploade their better (in terms of explanability?) answers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107330/discussion-between-jingeon-an-and-brian-m-scott).